# Github Visual Studio Pull : Will it include the Project's references?

Tags: github, visual-studio-2022

Github Visual Studio 2022 Git Pull : Will it include the Project's references?
Using Visual Studio 2022 with Git. When pulling from a hosted repository into my local machine, will that also automatically set the same project references in my local machine as it is in the hosted repositories?
What should be the expected behaviour?
Thank you

I tried but I see other references than other users on other machines.

Answer (score 0):

The project references should be defined in the .csproj file (or .vbproj, etc).  This file *should* be included in ones source control repository.

You may need to perform a nuget restore if the references are fetched from a package manager (i.e. https://nuget.org), especially if someone else modified the references and pushed them to your remote in GitHub

For example, someone else on your project updates a reference to a newer version and pushes it up to GitHub.  You then perform a `git pull` on the branch that these changes were made on, and suddenly you have new references or possibly see errors all over your code.  When this happens, you almost certainly need to perform a nuget restore to get the new package references.